# datetime strftime does not output correct timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

The following:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("2013-07-02 00:00:00 -0000")
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

shows that the time should be 12am on July 2nd 2013 in UTC.

However:

```
>>> parse("2013-07-02 00:00:00 -0000").strftime("%s")
'1372744800'
```

1372744800 is actually Tue, 02 Jul 2013 06:00:00 UTC, which is wrong.  Very confused.

Comment: Where are you importing `parse` from?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce; I get `1372741200` (an hour earlier). Pretty sure this is a time zone issue.

Comment: that's still wrong, its just in a different TZ.  even weirder:  parse("2013-07-02 00:00:00 -0000").strftime("%s %z") will give you "1372744800 +0000", meaning strftime thinks it is in UTC.

Comment: related issue on Python bug tracker: [datetime.strftime('%s') should respect tzinfo](http://bugs.python.org/issue12750)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question: [Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime)

> Python doesn't actually support %s as an argument to strftime (if you
>   check at
>   http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior
>   it's not in the list), the only reason it's working is because Python
>   is passing the information to your system's strftime, which uses your
>   local timezone.

Comment: thanks, that worked.  people say python is a far superior language than PHP (where i'm coming from), but in PHP with DateTime, that wouldn't have been nearly as hard or confusing.

Comment: You should checkout [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) and [delorean](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean). These makes it easy to wirk with datetimes. Also [check out this thread on reddit!](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1c2dra/what_are_the_best_practices_to_work_with_time_in/)