# datetime with pytz timezone. Different offset depending on how tzinfo is set

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I ran across an interesting situation today. Can anyone explain why the offsets for ts1 and ts2 are different? ts1 is a datetime object that is timezone-aware right off the bat. ts2 is a datetime object that starts off timezone-naive and has its tzinfo replaced. However, they end up with different offsets.

```
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> EST = timezone('America/New_York')
>>> ts1 = datetime.datetime.now(tz=EST)
>>> ts2 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> ts2 = ts2.replace(tzinfo=EST)
>>> print ts1
2014-05-16 11:25:16.749748-04:00
>>> print ts2
2014-05-16 11:25:19.581710-05:00
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `ts2.replace(tzinfo=EST)`, the `tzinfo` object you're getting doesn't match the one you get with `ts1`:

```
>>> ts1
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 16, 11, 51, 7, 916090, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
>>> ts2
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 16, 11, 51, 30, 922692, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)
```

You end up with LMT instead of EDT.

The `pytz` [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) actually notes that using `pytz` with the `tzinfo` argument of standard datetime objects simply doesn't work for many timezones:

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime
>   constructors ''does not work'' with pytz for many timezones.
>
> `>>> datetime(2002, 10, 27, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=amsterdam).strftime(fmt) '2002-10-27 12:00:00 LMT+0020'`
>
> It is safe for timezones without daylight saving transitions though,
>   such as UTC:
>
> `>>> datetime(2002, 10, 27, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc).strftime(fmt) '2002-10-27 12:00:00 UTC+0000'`

I'm not exactly sure why the first one works; perhaps because it doesn't actually have to convert anything when the object is initially constructed with the `tzinfo` object.

**Edit**:

Ah, the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) notes that using `datetime.datetime.now()` with the `tz` arg is equivalent to:

```
EST.fromutc(datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=EST))
```

Which means you're converting from UTC, which is safe with `pytz`. So that's why the first one works.

Comment: `pytz` provides the custom implementation for `.fromutc()` method that uses `._utc_transition_times` list to get the correct tzinfo object.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), the correct way to apply a time zone to a naive datetime is with the `localize` method.

```
ts1 = eastern.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Also, I recommend you use avoid `EST` as a variable name, since it typically standard for "Eastern Standard Time", and `America/New_York` comprises both "Eastern Standard Time" (EST) and "Eastern Daylight Time" (EDT).

Comment: it may return an incorrect result during DST transitions, use `datetime.now(eastern)` instead.