# Datetime object with same timezone but different utcoffset()

Tags: python, django, datetime

In my django application i'm confronting two datetime objects (self.dueDate is a date object):

```
ref_time = timezone.localtime(timezone.now(), timezone.get_default_timezone() )
threshold = datetime.combine( self.dueDate, 
                               time(tzinfo=timezone.get_default_timezone())) 
           - timedelta(days = 1)
```

I'm constructing them to have the same timezone (which they have), but they end up having two different UTC offsets.

```
>>>print threshold, threshold.tzinfo
2015-03-13 12:08:00+00:50 Europe/Rome 
>>>print ref_time, ref_time.tzinfo
2015-03-13 12:48:29.372984+01:00 Europe/Rome
```

Why is this happening? How can it be that there are two different offsets for the same tz? (and why would that offest be 50 minutes?)

Comment: unrelated: make sure you know the difference between [default time zone and current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-current-time-zone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timezone may have different utc offsets at different times. `time(tzinfo=tz)` uses a default utc offset e.g., for the earliest date that is most likely is *not* what you want. See:

- [Datetime Timezone conversion using pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27531718/4279)
- [datetime with pytz timezone. Different offset depending on how tzinfo is set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23699115/4279)
- [pytz localize vs datetime replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379740/pytz-localize-vs-datetime-replace#comment41069172_1379874)

To get the current time in `tz` timezone as an aware datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime

ref_time = datetime.now(tz)
```

To get a midnight a day before `self.dueDate` as an aware datetime object:

```
from datetime import time as datetime_time, timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

midnight_yesterday = datetime.combine(self.dueDate, datetime_time()) - timedelta(1)
threshold = timezone.make_aware(midnight_yesterday)
```

Note: `threshold` may be more/less than 24 hours ago, see [How can I subtract a day from a python date?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25427822/4279).

Comment: Thanks a lot, using timezone.make_aware() instead of setting the tzinfo did it. You saved my day!

Comment: @pnjun: be careful if you perform datetime arithmetics that may cross DST boundary. `make_aware()` along won't fix it e.g., if you want exactly 24 hours ago then you need a different code. See the last link in the answer.