# DateOffset from Year to Month and Week

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am pulling a chunk of data within a range of time. It is pulling date and times from column recvd_dttm. It takes all the data starting from a year ago. I want to modify it so that it can pull a month or a day, but pd.DateOffset(months=1) is giving a `KeyError:1` error. I get the same error if I change it to days=7. But it works just fine with years=1. What is going on here?

```
df = pd.read_csv('MYDATA.csv')

# filter by countries with at least one medal and sort
df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'])

#Only retrieve data before now (ignore typos that are future dates)
mask = df['recvd_dttm'] <= datetime.datetime.now()
df = df.loc[mask]
# get first and last datetime for final week of data

range_max = df['recvd_dttm'].max()
range_min = range_max - pd.DateOffset(years=1)

# take slice with final week of data
df = df[(df['recvd_dttm'] >= range_min) & 
               (df['recvd_dttm'] <= range_max)]
```

EDIT: The problem was coming from elsewhere in the code!

Comment: can you clarify what your end purpose is?  is it to get the max values for every year?

Comment: No. The end purpose is to have a slice of data from a certain range that a user inputs. They pick a day, a month, a year, and it pulls that amount of data from the csv.

Comment: what about the range_max and range_min lines?  what are you hoping those are trying accomplish?  are those just the start and stops of the chosen range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried being more explicit with what pd.DateOffset is acting on?

For example:

```
range_max = df['recvd_dttm'].max()
range_min = range_max - (df['recvd_dttm']+pd.DateOffset(years=1))
```

Then substitute month and days values.

Comment: The thing is that pd.DateOffset(years=1) is working just fine. Substituting months and days is causing errors. Using your suggestion I got the error TypeError: cannot use a non-absolute DateOffset in datetime/timedelta operations [<DateOffset: kwds={'years': 1}>] Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: hm can you provide a single row of data for me to play with?

Comment: I have an example column for you. Hope that helps!

Comment: for your example column i'm able to use your original code without a problem.  the days and months are working.  could it be a data issue?

Comment: Wow, yes, it is a data issue. Thanks for helping me realize that. The original code later goes through by months that year, but obviously if you take a month of code, no January is available. I have to work on that now, thank you!

Comment: If you're interested, the question for fixing this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412541/modifying-code-to-work-for-month-and-week-instead-of-year

Answer (score 1):

You can use the offset family from `pd.tseries.offsets`. Below is the sample code.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# your data
# ================================
df = pd.read_csv('/home/Jian/Downloads/MOCK_DATA.csv', usecols=[1, 4])

df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'])
mask = df['recvd_dttm'] <= datetime.datetime.now()
df = df.loc[mask]


# flexible offsets
# =======================================
print(range_max)

2015-07-14 16:52:58

# for 1 month: currently there is a bug
# range_min_month = range_max - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset(1)

# for 1 week
range_min_week = range_max - pd.tseries.offsets.Week(1)
print(range_min_week)

2015-07-07 16:52:58

# for 5 days
range_min_day = range_max - pd.tseries.offsets.Day(5)
print(range_min_day)

2015-07-09 16:52:58
```

Comment: Thank you Jianxun! I actually realized that this question was pretty stupid, as the issue was elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `timedelta` instead of `DateOffset`

Comment: I should have written this as something I've tried. I don't want to do timedelta(days=30) or anything for a month because it is inaccurate for some months. If I try months=1 I get TypeError: 'months' is an invalid keyword argument for this function. Same for years=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using Unix Epoch Time instead of a date formatted in a lesser manner?  There is a well documented [answer for converting to Unix Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python), and dealing with the sort of offset in the question seems like it would be a lot easier as sliding ranges are simpler to implement with a more or less continuous sequence of real numeric values.