# Modifying Code to work for Month and Week instead of Year

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, pandas, date-range

I am making a stacked bar plot over a year time span where the x-axis is company names, y-axis is the number of calls, and the stacks are the months.

I want to be able to make this plot run for a time span of a month, where the stacks are days, and a time span of a week, where the stacks are days. I am having trouble doing this since my code is built already around the year time span.

My input original input is a csv file. I am pulling two rows like this:

```
CompanyName     recvd_dttm
Company1        6/5/2015 18:28:50 PM
Company2        6/5/2015 14:25:43 PM
Company3        9/10/2015 21:45:12 PM
Company4        6/5/2015 14:30:43 PM
Company5        6/5/2015 14:32:33 PM
```

Then I make a datatable that looks like this

```
pivot_table.head(3)
Out[12]: 
Month       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11   12 
CompanyName                                                                     
Customer1   17  30  29  39  15  26  24  12  36  21  18   15  
Customer2   4   11  13  22  35  29  15  18  29  31  17   14
Customer3   11   8  25  24   7  15  20   0  21  12  12   17
```

and my code is this so far.

First I grab a years worth of data (I would change this to a month or a week for this question)

```
# filter by countries with at least one medal and sort
df['recvd_dttm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recvd_dttm'])

#Only retrieve data before now (ignore typos that are future dates)
mask = df['recvd_dttm'] <= datetime.datetime.now()
df = df.loc[mask]
# get first and last datetime for final week of data

range_max = df['recvd_dttm'].max()
range_min = range_max - pd.DateOffset(years=1)

# take slice with final week of data
df = df[(df['recvd_dttm'] >= range_min) & 
               (df['recvd_dttm'] <= range_max)]
```

Then I create the pivot_table shown above.

```
###########################################################
#Create Dataframe
###########################################################

df = df.set_index('recvd_dttm')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

result = df.groupby([lambda idx: idx.month, 'CompanyName']).agg(len).reset_index()
result.columns = ['Month', 'CompanyName', 'NumberCalls']
pivot_table = result.pivot(index='Month', columns='CompanyName', values='NumberCalls').fillna(0)
s = pivot_table.sum().sort(ascending=False,inplace=False)
pivot_table = pivot_table.ix[:,s.index[:30]]
pivot_table = pivot_table.transpose()
pivot_table = pivot_table.reset_index()
pivot_table['CompanyName'] = [str(x) for x in pivot_table['CompanyName']]
Companies = list(pivot_table['CompanyName'])
pivot_table = pivot_table.set_index('CompanyName')
pivot_table.to_csv('pivot_table.csv')
```

Then I use the pivot table to create an OrderedDict for Plotting

```
###########################################################
#Create OrderedDict for plotting
###########################################################


months = [pivot_table[(m)].astype(float).values for m in range(1, 13)]
names = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov", "Dec"]
months_dict = OrderedDict(list(zip(names, months)))

###########################################################
#Plot!
###########################################################


palette = brewer["RdYlGn"][8]

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("Month", "@months"),
        ("Number of Calls", "@NumberCalls"),
        ]
)
output_file("stacked_bar.html")
bar = Bar(months_dict, Companies, title="Number of Calls Each Month", palette = palette, legend = "top_right", width = 1200, height=900, stacked=True)
bar.add_tools(hover)


show(bar)
```

[image]

Does anyone have ideas on how to approach modifying this code so it can work for shorter time spans? I am thinking that it will be modification in the OrderedDict section. Possibly making len(recvd_dttm) to iterate over?

Answer (score 1):

For days in a month ('2015-07' say) You could change

```
result = df.groupby([lambda idx: idx.month, 'CompanyName']).agg(len).reset_index()
```

to something like

```
month = '2015-07'
result = df.loc[month].groupby([lambda idx: idx.day, 'CompanyName']).agg(len).reset_index()
```

And replace `'Month'` with `'Day'` below. You wouldn't have to bother with the OrderedDict etc. in this case as they are just ints. For a week you could do

```
start, end = '2015-07-06', '2015-07-12'
result = df.loc[start: end].groupby(
            [lambda idx: idx.dayofweek, 'CompanyName']).agg(len).reset_index()
```

Comment: If I don't bother with the OrderedDict, what are the variables I put in bar? Does it know how many days to put in for a specific month or hours for a day?

Comment: Well I'm not sure as I don't know what the API is for that `Bar` class is. I assumed you used an ordered dict so that the names of the months would be sorted chronologically rather than lexographically. From which module did you import it? It's new to me but looks useful. My guess is that you would use the index of `pivot_table`, which would be the days in the month or week, in some way but not sure. I've never seen `HoverTool` either.

Comment: It is from bokeh. Here is the code of something from the gallery I was pulling from. http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stacked_bar_chart.html