# Sort timestamp in python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, timestamp

```
mydict = [{'Counted number': '26', 'Timestamp': '8/10/2015 13:07:38'},{'Counted number': '14','Timestamp': '8/10/2015 11:51:14'},{'Counted number': '28','Timestamp': '8/10/2015 13:06:27'}, {'Counted number': '20','Timestamp': '8/10/2015 12:53:42'}]
```

How to sort this dict based on timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mydict.sort(key=lambda x:x['Timestamp'])
```

This will compare the elements of `mydict` based on their time stamp and sort it that way. Now, if you want to sort it by the actual time, then you have to convert that timestamp string to a `Time` object of some sort, and then sort `mydict` based on that. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python) will likely help with that.

Comment: This treats the timestamp as a string and sorts on that. If the first entry was `08/10/2015 13:07:38` instead of `8/10/2015 13:07:38`, this method would give incorrect result.

Comment: @agamagarwal: Yes, I know. Did you not read my second sentence?

Comment: I'm just getting `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Comment: @Marki The original question has a list of dicts.

Answer (score 10):

This should work

```
import time
mydict.sort(key=lambda x:time.mktime(time.strptime(x['Timestamp'], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')))
```