# How to convert this string to Unix time?

Tags: python

How to convert this string to Unix time?
t = '20160224122738'

I can write a function to do this, but wanted to know if there was an already-existing simple method that I could use.

Comment: Is that supposed to `12:27:38 PM` on February 24, 2016?

Comment: Yes. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/466366/3991164).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string date to timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way that comes to mind would be:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> t = '20160224122738'
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").timetuple())
1456309658.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = '20160224122738'
>>> int(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').strftime("%s"))
1456297058
```