# Converting time to epoch (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, tweepy, epoch

I am using tweepy to get a tweet. I am trying to send this tweet over Slack. Tweepy gives the time in a strange format, and Slack requires the time in epoch.

```
for i in tweets:
    created=(i.created_at)
    print(created)
    print(created.strftime('%s'))
```

This returns

```
2017-01-17 14:36:26

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\slackbot3\run.py", line 287, in main
print(created.strftime('%s'))
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

How can I get 2017-01-17 14:36:26 into epoch time?

Comment: I think, its a dublicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python

Comment: If `created_at` is a `datetime` object, there are other questions that solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p

Comment: @jdehesa Does not look like _datetime_ object - looks like string

Comment: @volcano I don't think it's a string, because the object has a `strftime` method - but it does not seem to be a datetime either, because `'%s'` should be a valid format string. Maybe seeing the result of `print(type(created))` could help.

Comment: BTW, are you sure it's Python 2.7? You use _print_ function...

Comment: @volcano: They used parentheses, but since there was only one "argument", it would work equivalently with the `print` statement or `print` function.

Answer (score 7):

You have to convert the string to time tuple -by appropriate spec,  and then time tuple to EPOCH time. In Python it's a little bit awkward

```
import time
time_tuple = time.strptime('2017-01-17 14:36:26', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time_epoch = time.mktime(time_tuple)
```

The result is *1484656586.0*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the type of `created` but this should work:

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.strptime(str(created), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%s'))
```