# Check date is within one year python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date string formatted like this: `"2017-05-31T06:44:13Z"`.

I need to check whether this date is within a one year span from today's date.

Which is the best method to do it: convert it into a timestamp and check, or convert into a date format?

Comment: _"i can not convert into date object."_ Please clarify. Do you mean "I tried to convert it into a date object, but I could not figure out how"? Or do you mean "I know how to convert it into a date object, but my (teacher | boss | online submission judge) forbids me from doing so"?

Comment: i tried to convert into date object using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python .But error ocuured

Comment: ValueError: time data '2017-05-31T06:44:13Z' does not match format 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'
@Kevin

Answer (score 3):

Convert the timestamp to a datetime object so it can be compared with other datetime objects using `<`, `>`, `=`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# NOTE this format basically ignores the timezone. This may or may not be what you want
date_to_check = datetime.strptime('2017-05-31T06:44:13Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
today = datetime.today()
one_year_from_now = today + relativedelta(years=1)


if today <= date_to_check <= one_year_from_now:
    #   do whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `datetime` package together with `timedelta`:

```
import datetime
then = datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-05-31T06:44:13Z".replace('T',' ')[:-1],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 365)
```

and simply check `if now-d > then`.

Comment: Not all years have 365 days ;)

Comment: Fair enough. But OP says "within one year span" not "same day, one year ago" and in most applications 1y=365d.