# Python - Convert Date string to UTC timestamp

Tags: python, date, utc

I have a string that says "Oct. 2, 2017, midnight" and want to convert it to a UTC timestamp.

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: are all the hours midnight?

Comment: Yeah all the hours are midnight. I actually did a little searching and found it seems to just be a normal date object with the format:

2017-10-02 00:00:00+00:00

Comment: Did you copy/paste your post title into Google and go through all the solutions?

Comment: If all your data are "midnight" then it's trivial, just strip the last part of the string and pass it to `datetime.strptime()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string date to timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I thought the same but the "midnight" string is kind of an interesting variant on the common problem.

Answer (score 2):

Considering all your data is at midnight, the easiest way is to remove the `, midnight` string and convert it.

```
import datetime
import pytz
s = "Oct. 2, 2017, midnight"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s.split(', midnight')[0], '%b. %d, %Y')
dt_utc = dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

If there are other time indicated, you'll want to interpret the literals of the time and pass it onto `strptime()` accordingly.