# How to convert date given as a string into a unix time stamp, including the time zone, and the month is given as a abbreviaton

Tags: python, date, unix-timestamp

I have the following string:

```
08 Jan 2018 08:45:30 +0100
```

which I would like to conert to a unix timestamp. I know how to convert a time from this answer [Convert string date to timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python) , however this only describes how to do it if the name is given as a number like `01/12/1991`. Furthermore, I do not know how to include the timezoen (+0100) into the conversion.

For the month I would have come up with a look up table which is a workaround, and I thought there may be a better way to do this

Here is the code I came up with for that:

```
lookup = {}


lookup['Jan'] = '01'
lookup['Feb'] = '02'
lookup['Mar'] = '03'
lookup['Apr'] = '04'
lookup['Mai'] = '05'
lookup['Jun'] = '06'
lookup['Jul'] = '07'
lookup['Aug'] = '08'
lookup['Sep'] = '09'
lookup['Okt'] = '10'
lookup['Nov'] = '11'
lookup['Dec'] = '12'

dates_to_convert = '08 Jan 2018 08:45:30 +0100'


dates_to_convert.replace(dates_to_convert.split()[1],lookup[dates_to_convert.split()[1]])

## Now continue with solution from linked answer...
```

Comment: Do look at the [documentation for `datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and you'll see there is a pattern matcher for abbreviated month names too.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters thank you - but what about the timezone?

Comment: Did you scan the table further down? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to look at the [`datetime.strptime()` documentation on patterns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), you'll see that the `%b` pattern matches abbreviated month names, and `%z` handles a timezone offset:

> `%b`  Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
>
> [...]
>
> `%z`  UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the object is naive).

Unless you set a locale, the default `C` locale matches US month names out of the box.

For your string, the pattern is `%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dates_to_convert = '08 Jan 2018 08:45:30 +0100'
>>> datetime.strptime(dates_to_convert, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 8, 8, 45, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `datetime.strptime` to parse your string and `datetime.timestamp` to output a UNIX timestamp

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp

Something like this should work:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime('08 Jan 2018 08:45:30 +0100', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z').timestamp()
>>> 1515397530.0
```

If you want the integer part only (seconds):

```
timestamp = datetime.strptime('08 Jan 2018 08:45:30 +0100', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z').timestamp()
timestamp = int(timestamp)
>>> 1515397530
```