# ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 28/06/2016

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i have a probleme

```
for i in range(len(member_KPIs)) : 
    member_id = member_KPIs.loc[i,"ID_SAFAR"]

#member_activity['ACTIVITY_DATE'] = pd.to_numeric(member_activity['ACTIVITY_DATE'])

#print(member_id)
member_id_filter = member_activity["MEMBER_ID"] == member_id
filtered_members_activity = member_activity[member_id_filter]

max_activity_date = max(filtered_members_activity["ACTIVITY_DATE"])

member_KPIs.at[i,'LAST_TRAVEL_DATE'] = max_activity_date
```

Comment: On which line it throws the error?

Comment: in this line ...............................................................................................max_activity_date = max(filtered_members_activity["ACTIVITY_DATE"])

member_KPIs.at[i,'LAST_TRAVEL_DATE'] = max_activity_date

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the error on this line:

```
max_activity_date = max(filtered_members_activity["ACTIVITY_DATE"])
```

It seems like you're trying to give a list of strings to the max() function, which will not work; max() expects numbers (i.e. floats), not date strings. If you need to compare these dates, you can try just converting them to timestamps:

```
import time, datetime #required for timestamp conversion
#quick and dirty list comprehension
max_activity_date = max([time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple()) for s in filtered_members_activity["ACTIVITY_DATE"])
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python) are some answers on getting a timestamp from the date.