# Tuple or struct_time argument required error while using time.mktime(datetime.strptime(ti, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'))

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a code snippet which looks like this:

```
Logger_time = [
    '6/30/2020 3:15 PM', '6/30/2020 3:16 PM',
    '6/30/2020 3:17 PM', '6/30/2020 3:18 PM',
    '6/30/2020 3:19 PM', '6/30/2020 3:20 PM',
    '6/30/2020 3:21 PM', '6/30/2020 3:22 PM',
    '6/30/2020 3:23 PM', '6/30/2020 3:24 PM',
    '6/30/2020 3:25 PM', '6/30/2020 3:26 PM',
    '6/30/2020 3:27 PM', '6/30/2020 3:28 PM',
    '6/30/2020 3:29 PM', '6/30/2020 3:30 PM',
    '6/30/2020 3:31 PM', '6/30/2020 3:32 PM',
    '6/30/2020 3:33 PM', '6/30/2020 3:34 PM']

newLoggertime = []

for ti in Logger_time:

    timestamp = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(ti, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'))
    newLoggertime.append(timestamp)
```

When I run this code I have suddenly started getting this error

```
TypeError: Tuple or struct_time argument required
```

I cant seem to find the reason behind this. Basically this code converts date and time in a particular format to timestamp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string date to timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python)

Comment: No but I found what the problem was: timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(ti, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'))

Comment: ok I admit the answers there do not exactly match your use-case and partly aren't up to date anymore. anyway, I think @Kemp 's answer shows an easier way: just use the timestamp method of the datetime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.strptime` returns a `datetime` object, while `time.mktime` requires a tuple, as the message states.

Your options are to call `timetuple` on the `datetime` object and pass this to `time.mktime`:

```
timestamp = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(ti, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p').timetuple())
```

or call `timestamp` on the `datetime` object to get the timestamp directly:

```
timestamp = datetime.strptime(ti, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p').timestamp()
```

Though be aware of the notes related to [`timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp).

Comment: Right. If I use time instead of datetime it works as well.                                               
         timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(ti, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'))