# How to convert current date time with hh:mm:ss into timestamp in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have two date-time string like "1637279999" that converts into "Thursday, 18 November 2021 23:59:59" and "1637193600" that converts into "Thursday, 18 November 2021 00:00:00". I converted using https://www.epochconverter.com/.

Is there any python function that converts directly current date-time (with HH:MM:SS) into the following formats?

String 1: Thursday, 18 November 2021 23:59:59 => 1637279999

String 2: Thursday, 18 November 2021 00:00:00 => 1637193600

Comment: Note: `time.time()` function gives current date time.

Comment: Use `strptime` to parse to datetime, set tzinfo (if certain time zone instead of local time), then use `.timestamp` method. Just have a look at the datetime module docs :)

Comment: @MrFuppes I am not getting "23:59:59" just works for "00:00:00". Is there any direct function for this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string date to timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the date, add TimeZone info to that, then get the timestamp from it.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone


def to_timestamp(date_str):
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S')
    date_obj = date_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)  # replace your desired TZ here
    return date_obj.timestamp()
```