# Python: converting timestamp to date time not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, etherscan

I am requesting data from the `api.etherscan.io` website. For this, I require a free API key. I am getting information for the following wallet addresses `0xdafea492d9c6733ae3d56b7ed1adb60692c98bc5, 0xc508dbe4866528db024fb126e0eb97595668c288`. Below is the code I am using:

```
wallet_addresses = ['0xdafea492d9c6733ae3d56b7ed1adb60692c98bc5', '0xc508dbe4866528db024fb126e0eb97595668c288']

page_number = 0
df_main = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
    for address in wallet_addresses:
        url=f'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address={address}&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page={page_number}&offset=10&sort=asc&apikey={ether_api}'
        output = requests.get(url).text
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(output)['result'])
        df_temp['wallet_address'] = address
        df_main = df_main.append(df_temp)
        page_number += 1
        df_main['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_main['timeStamp'], unit='s')
        if min(pd.to_datetime(df_main['timeStamp']).dt.date) < datetime.date(2022, 1, 1):
            pass
```

Note that you need your own (free) `ether_api`.

What I want to do is get data from today's date, all the way back to `2022-01-01` which is what I am trying to achieve in the if statement.

However, the above gives me an error: `ValueError: unit='s' not valid with non-numerical val='2022-09-19 18:14:47'`

How can this be done? I've tried multiple methods to get pandas datetime to work, but all of them gave me errors.

Comment: What does `type(df_main['timeStamp'].iloc[0]` show?

Comment: It shows this: `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`

Comment: If it is already a timestamp, then maybe a conversion is not needed and you can use the object directly to find the date?

Comment: Yes, should be fine. I've already registered to get api, will take a look

Comment: Also [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.date.html#pandas.Timestamp.date). you can extract the date by doing a `df_main['timeStamp'].date`

Comment: @LucaZangari I've tried that but gives an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: Have you considered using `datetime` lib? Apply `strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` to all values in the column to parse the timestamps

Comment: just use `pd.to_datetime(df_main['timeStamp'])`. unit='s' is used if your input is Unix time as seconds since the epoch. If your input already is converted to datetime, remove the call to pd.to_datetime.

Comment: @lotrus28 that did not work either for me

Comment: @FObersteiner that also did not work

Comment: please verify that your example is reproducible -> [mre]

Comment: Yes, it is reproducible, I found the error. In a `for` loop on first iteration there is `1663611287` which is super fine to convert. But on next iteration there is `2022-09-19 18:14:47`, a date that does not need conversion. You need to supply your code with `if` statement checking for type of values you get in `df_main['timeStamp']` on each iteration.

Comment: @DiMithras Alright, thank you. I'll try to do that!

Comment: @MathMan99 actually, the api is fine, it only provides timestamps. What's happening here, you have `df_main = df_main.append(df_temp)`, that means you mix `timestamps` with casted `datetime`. that results in an error. You need to rework the logic on appending, so that when you cast `timestamps` to date, you do it only on `df_temp` and only than add it to `df_main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, it's working without an error:

```
page_number = 0
df_main = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
    for address in wallet_addresses:
        url=f'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address={address}&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page={page_number}&offset=10&sort=asc&apikey={ether_api}'
        output = requests.get(url).text
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(output)['result'])
        df_temp['wallet_address'] = address
        page_number += 1
        df_temp['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_temp['timeStamp'], unit='s')
        df_main = df_main.append(df_temp)
        if min(pd.to_datetime(df_main['timeStamp']).dt.date) < datetime(2022, 1, 1).date():
            pass
```

---

##### Wrong append

So, what has happened here. As suggested in the first comment under question we acknowledged the `type` of first record in `df_main` with `type(df_main['timeStamp'].iloc[0])`. With [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) and [Jupyter-Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) one can look what is happening with `df_main` just after receiving an error with it being populated on the last `for` loop iteration that failed.
Otherwise if one uses [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) or any other IDE with a possibility to debug, the contents of `df_main` can be revealed via debug.

What we were missing, is that `df_main = df_main.append(df_temp)` is placed in a slightly wrong place. On first iteration it works well, `pd.to_datetime(df_main['timeStamp'], unit='s')` gets an `str` **type** with Linux epoch and gets converted to `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`.

But on next iteration `df_main['timeStamp']` already has the **Timestamp type** and it gets appended with `str` **type**, so we get a column with mixed type. E.g.:

```python
type(df_main['timeStamp'].iloc[0]) == type(df_main['timeStamp'].iloc[-1])
```

This results with **False**. Hence when trying to convert **Timestamp** to **Timestamp** one gets an error featured in question.

To mitigate this we can place `.append()` below the conversion and do this conversion on `df_temp` instead of `df_main`, this way we will only append **Timestamp**s to the resulting DataFrame and the code below with `if` clause will work fine.

###### As a side note

Another small change I've made was `datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)`. This change was not needed, but the way one works with `datetime` depends on how this library was imported, so it's worth mentioning:

```python
import datetime
datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)
datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1).date()

from datetime import datetime
datetime(2022, 1, 1).date()
```

All the above is legit and will produce the same. On the first import `module` gets imported, on the second one `type` gets imported.

---

### Alternative solution

Conversion to **Timestamp** takes time. If the API provides Linux epoch dates, why not use this date for comparison? Let's add this somewhere where you define `wallet_addresses`:

```python
reference_date = "01/01/2021"
reference_date = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(reference_date, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple()))
```

This will result in **1609448400**. Other stack overflow question as [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python).

This integer can now be compared with timestamps provided by the API. The only thing left is to cast `str` to `int`. We can have your code left intact with some minor changes at the end:

```python
<< Your code without changes >>
        df_main['timeStamp'] = df_main['timeStamp'].astype(int)
        if min(df_main['timeStamp']) < reference_date:
            pass
```

To make a benchmark I've changed `while True:` to `for _ in range(0,4):` to limit the infinite cycle, results are as follows:

- Initial solution took 11.6 s to complete
- Alternative solution took 8.85 s to complete

It's 30% faster. Casting `str` to `int` takes less time than conversion to **TimeStamp**s, I would call this a preferable solution.

## Future warning

```console
FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
```

It makes sense to comply with this warning. `df_main = df_main.append(df_temp)` has to be changed to `df_main = pd.concat([df_main, df_temp])`.

As for current 1.5.0 version it's already [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append). Time to upgrade!

Comment: The error is now coming from `datetime(2022,1,1)` saying `TypeError: module is not callable`. But the other error is solved. Did it work on your end?

Comment: Yeah, I changed it a bit as I was getting the error there . Change `datetime(2022, 1, 1).date()` back to `datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)` if it's working for you. Might be a different python / library version or the way we import `datetime`. I do with `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: I gave it a try. And, yes, it's a different way we import `datetime`. My bad, I should have mentioned it.

Comment: @MathMan99 answer updated with an alternative solution.