# ValueError: Could not convert string to float: Date-time.000000

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

uh I'm kinda sure that this is quite easy to solve but I couldn't...

I'm having this error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2017-08-31 18:06:36.000000'
```

The code I'm using is the next:

```
url = "train_set.csv"
names = ['ID', 'order_status', 'order_products_value', 'order_freight_value', 'order_items_qty', 'order_sellers_qty', 'order_purchase_timestamp', 'order_aproved_at', 'order_estimated_delivery_date', 'order_delivered_customer_date', 'customer_city', 'customer_state', 'customer_zip_code_prefix', 'product_category_name_english', 'product_name_lenght', 'product_description_lenght', 'product_photos_qty', 'target']
dataset = read_csv(url, names=names)

print(dataset.shape)

print(dataset.head(100))

print("-----------------------------------------------------------------")

print(dataset.describe())

dataset.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, layout=[12,2], sharex=False, sharey=False)
pyplot.show()

array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:17]
y = array[:,17]
print(y)
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)

models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', multi_class='ovr')))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC(gamma='auto')))


# Here is where the errors are shown


results = []
names = []
print("---- X - Train ---------")
print(X_train)
print(Y_train)

for name, model in models:
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
    print(name)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold.get_n_splits(X_train, Y_train), scoring='accuracy')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s: %f (%f)' % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

Any idea? - I think the error is in the models part... but I'm not sure, I'm quite new working with machine learning...

> Edit: The idea is to obtain the Unix time

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: what number do you expect to get from the string `2017-08-31 18:06:36.000000`?  Are you trying to obtain the UNIX time?

Comment: Ah yeh I forgot to mention it, yes the idea is to have it as Unix time

Comment: Ok, so you don;t neet to include all the code regarding machine learning. Your question is: How to convert a datetime string to unix time, which you can get the answer in this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637838/convert-string-date-to-timestamp-in-python

Comment: I see... so I after importing it I need to add this before creating the models part?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the string date time i.e. '2017-08-31 18:06:36.000000' to Unix time, then you can use dateutil.parser. Here is the example:

```
import dateutil.parser
my_date = '2017-08-31 18:06:36.000000'
my_ts = dateutil.parser.parse(my_date, dayfirst=True).timestamp()
print(my_ts)
```

Corresponding output:

```
1504202796.0
```

Comment: Thanks! uh but this date comes from a csv file, how could it be added if that's the case?

Comment: You can create a function with argument as your string value and feed the values that you are getting from csv file.